# How to create this complex layout in tailwind?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, tailwind-css

I want to create a layout like below with tailwind. I don't know how to make the blue area have full width but the purple area has a limit at 9/12 grid.

12 column is max 1200px.

[image]

Here is my code:

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container lg:w-1200px bg-red-500 mx-auto flex">
  <div class="w-3/12 bg-blue-500 grid place-items-center h-screen">3/12</div>
  <div class="w-9/12 h-80 relative">
    <div class="bg-yellow-500 h-20"></div>
    <div class="bg-green-500 h-screen grid place-items-center">9/12</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Maybe it's just complex with me, not you. So sorry about that. Thanks!

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: I created a layout that looks like the one to achieve, have a look [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/JrkZBeGi7V). I think the most useful point is positioning the blue box ´absolute´ly relative to screen, and use classes `w-screen` and `right-0` and z-indices. Please have a quick to look to it to check if I understood the requirements well, and if not, please edit your answer to be more specific about the requirements. If it's ok, I'll make it an answer.

Comment: @kenshuri thank you, but I want the blue shape take position from red shape to right-0

Comment: I don't know... Adding some fixed padding left could make it "look" like the blue shape take position from red shape as in https://play.tailwindcss.com/dMFTmAH8by , but I agree it is not satisfactory. Please update question if you manage to achieve what you want.

Comment: @kenshuri Hi, the designer just update that the blue area can be limited, I think you are right, please make the answer <3

Comment: Thanks for following-up, I'll add the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create the target layout

- `absolute`ly position the blue box relative to screen, using `w-screen` class so that it takes the entire screen width
- use a standard `grid` layout for other boxes, relying on `col-span` classes to size them according to requirements
- finally, use `w-[1200px]` class to set the width of the grid layout, and add a left-padding `pl-[300px]` to the blue box so that its content is away from the red box. As using these "pixel-perfet" arbitrary classes does not work in the code snippet, I replaced them respectively with `w-96` and `pl-24`

See below an implementation example

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^2/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="w-96 h-screen bg-red-100 grid grid-cols-12">
  <div class="bg-red-500 col-span-3 z-20 relative">Something in red</div>
  <div class="bg-blue-500 w-full absolute pl-24 h-12 z-0">Something in blue</div>
  <div class="bg-purple-700 col-span-9 z-20 transform translate-y-7">Something in purple</div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```